# UIKit crash when deleting / inserting rows into UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my `UiTableView` I load dynamic data into it and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the `UITableView` i then load more items and insert them into the bottom of the table. This works without issues. However, if the users loads the items, then deletes one item and scrolls to the bottom (To load more items) the app crashes.

From what I can work out, there is a mismatch in the dataSource or the count when inserting items into the `table virew` - I just cannot work out where I've gone wrong.

This is the code I am using:

```
NSIndexSet  *indexSectionsToInsert = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(questionsCount, [questions.questionsAndAnswersArray count])];


[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if (loadingMore){

    NSIndexPath *indexSectionsToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:[currentArray count]];

    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexSectionsToDelete.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    loadingMore = NO;
}

[self.tableView insertSections:indexSectionsToInsert
          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];


[currentArray addObjectsFromArray:questions.questionsAndAnswersArray];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The crash happens when it tries to `deleteSections` inside the `loadingMore` if statement. The console shows:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (25) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (25), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

However when I check my counts they all appear to be correct. They are all at 24 which is the current number of sections in the tableview after the deletion.

It loads 25 items at a time into the tableview.

Here is what the indexes look like just before the crash happens:

**Deletion**:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000616> {length = 2, path = 24 - 0}
```

Which I see as "Delete sections 0 to 24" - which, in my mind is correct.

**Then the insertion:**

```
<NSIndexSet: 0x7f84c65ed0b0>[number of indexes: 25 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (24-48)]
```

Which I see as "Insert sections 24 to 48" - which, in my mind is correct.

I took a look at the above indexes under normal loading conditions and not after a deletion and it works fine: Here is what the indexes look like:

**Deletion**:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000616> {length = 2, path = 25 - 0}
```

**Then the insertion:**

```
<NSIndexSet: 0x7f84c65ed0b0>[number of indexes: 25 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (25-49)]
```

So only off by 1, which is correct as I only deleted one section. So, where is the issue?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't modify your storage (`currentArray`?) when you delete a section. This seems to be causing the crash.

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned, that gets modified in the tableViews commitEditingStyle method and current array does reflect this when I check the count 9Which is 24 in this case)

Comment: What if you move your storage modification code between those `...beginUpdates` and `...endUpdates` methods? I implemented similar functionality in an app just yesterday and it works perfect.

Comment: And problem solved. It seems in my commitEditingStyle method, I forgot to add ...beginUpdates and just had ..endUpdates after modifying the storage, so there was a mismatch. Please put your last comment into an answer so i can mark it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Done. Glad that hepled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your storage modification code between those `...beginUpdates` and `...endUpdates` methods.